# Delete all files in one folder via Apple Script

Tags: applescript

I worked out two scripts to do that, but none of them is working (I even don't get shown the "on error" message. Maybe it's because of the pre-defined folder as a variable? As for simplicity and a cleaner code I didn't want to write the complete path again, so I used that folder variable. In case it is relevant, the DataHubFolder variable was defined like this earlier: `set DataHubFolder to cloudDocs & "Current Projects:Data Hub:"`

Here are the codes I used:

Code #1:

```
            try
        
        tell application "Finder"
            set f to every file ¬
                of folder ¬
                of DataHubFolder & "Distrokid:"
            
            delete f
        end tell
        
    on error
        
        display dialog ("Error. Couldn't move the file") buttons {"OK"}
        
    end try
```

Code #2:

```
    try
        
        tell application "Finder"
            delete (every item of folder (DataHubFolder & "Distrokid:"))
        end tell
        
    on error
        
        display dialog ("Error. Couldn't move the file") buttons {"OK"}
        
    end try
```

Would be so happy about some tips.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first code makes no sense. The second is supposed to work.

Comment: thank you, I figured out, I set something up wrong earlier, so the script couldn't run. Now it does, but I get the error message (I set up) with the code -1728.

Comment: `display dialog` the full path and check it.

Comment: the full path didn't work, except when I changed `delete (every item of folder)` to `delete (every item of folder alias)`, still I needed to replace the pre-defined variable with the full path. But it's working now, that's a good thing. Thank you!